# Cannot mix 2018 and 2021 terms in call to TextTheme() constructor

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I upgraded version my flutter project to 3.0.0 in order to use null safety feature. When I run the project I got **Cannot mix 2018 and 2021 terms in call to TextTheme() constructor.** error.

> Cannot mix 2018 and 2021 terms in call to TextTheme() constructor.
> 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart':
> package:flutter/…/material/text_theme.dart:1
> Failed assertion: line 118 pos 10: '(displayLarge == null && displayMedium == null && displaySmall == null && headlineMedium == null &&
> headlineSmall == null && titleLarge == null && titleMedium == null && titleSmall == null &&
> bodyLarge == null && bodyMedium == null && bodySmall == null && labelLarge == null && labelSmall == null) ||
> (headline1 == null && headline2 == null && headline3 == null && headline4 == null &&
> headline5 == null && headline6 == null && subtitle1 == null && subtitle2 == null &&
> bodyText1 == null && bodyText2 == null && caption == null && button == null && overline == null)'

Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: go to your ThemeData() in your main.dart and modify TextTheme()

Answer (score 36):

@mister_cool_beans is correct.
Flutter is transitioning to Material 3 text style names for `TextTheme`. We are in the awkward period where both sets exist. See more [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/93725) for the commit associated with the change.

To be more clear, you **must only use** `terms` from the 2018 set **or** from the 2021 set. Update your `TextTheme/ThemeData` correspondingly. I suggest you take the opportunity to upgrade to 2021.

**2021 set**

```
displayLarge, displayMedium, displaySmall 
headlineLarge, headlineMedium, headlineSmall 
titleLarge, titleMedium, titleSmall 
bodyLarge, bodyMedium, bodySmall 
labelLarge, labelMedium, labelSmall
```

**2018 set**

```
headline1, headline2, headline3, headline4, headline5, headline6
subtitle1, subtitle2
bodyText1, bodyText2
caption, button, overline
```

As @Partick mentioned, if you scroll down to the implementation seen [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/TextTheme.html) you can see the sets defined in code.

```
...
}) : assert(
       (displayLarge == null && displayMedium == null && displaySmall == null && headlineMedium == null &&
           headlineSmall == null && titleLarge == null && titleMedium == null && titleSmall == null &&
           bodyLarge == null && bodyMedium == null && bodySmall == null && labelLarge == null && labelSmall == null) ||
       (headline1 == null && headline2 == null && headline3 == null && headline4 == null &&
           headline5 == null && headline6 == null && subtitle1 == null && subtitle2 == null &&
           bodyText1 == null && bodyText2 == null && caption == null && button == null && overline == null),
       'Cannot mix 2018 and 2021 terms in call to TextTheme() constructor.'
     ),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can not mix and match the 2018 styles with the 2021 styles. Only one or the other is allowed in this constructor. The 2018 styles will be deprecated and removed eventually. Source: [Source Document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/TextTheme.html)

Comment: You are using styles that came from 2018 and those from 2021 you cannot use them both you must use one set or the other. Kind of like using the color property and box decoration on a container both are not allowed. You will notice from the error message that it checks if you follow this rule